# Отслеживание обрыва соединения

Tags: python, c, python-2.x, twisted

Как в Python 2 с помощью Twisted 11.1 отследить потерю TCP соединения? Интересует "физический обрыв" соединения: например, мы выдернули шнур, в этом случае приложение должно сообщить пользователю сменой иконки. Реализовано ли это в Twisted 11.1, вообще? Система Linux. Конкретно ubuntu 12.04. Может быть это правильней реализовать на си? Или может быть правильней копать в сторону восстановления соединения?!

Answer (score 1):

TCP соединение может жить долгое долгое время после физического обрыва -- пока данные не посланы или если ([зависит от системы](https://serverfault.com/q/671710/3933) и приложения [`SO_KEEPALIVE`](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/#setsockopt)) TCP keepalives включены ([2 часа минимум согласно rfc 1122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#page-101)).

Чтобы не ждать и самостоятельно определить живо ли соединение, необходимо  послать данные на уровне выше tcp. Как конкретно heartbeat организован и релизован ли в twisted зависит от приложения и протоколов, в нём используемых, например у ssh есть `ServerAliveInterval` и `ServerAliveCountMax`.

Comment: То есть, необходимо послать второй стороне некий "KEEP_ALIVE" пакет и ждать ответа по какому-то тайм-ауту? Twisted тут не при чем?

Comment: @McMan: в общем случае, да.

Comment: Причём тут Си? Дополнительную информацию по вопросу (какая ОСь? что за приложение? зачем вообще обрыв отслеживать? например, большинство API предоставляют timeout параметр, чтобы вернуть ошибку вне зависимости живо TCP соединение или нет) следует в вопрос добавлять (или новый задать) вместо комментария.